# CSS border-bottom property not effective

Tags: html, css

I want to set up a bottom border for  an image slideshow. However, the css 
 `border-bottom` property is not acting properly. Any solutions?

I tried shortening the border property, but it still doesn't work.

```css
#slideshow {
   border-bottom-style: 5px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow" class="container-fluid">

       <!-- Full-width images with number text -->
        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
            <img src="y" style="width:100%">
        </div>

       <div class="mySlides">
           <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
           <img src="" style="width:100%">
       </div>

       <div class="mySlides">
           <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
           <img src="" style="width:100%">
       </div>

       <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
       <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
       <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

       <!-- Image text -->
      <div class="caption-container">
       <p id="caption"></p>
      </div>

      <!-- Thumbnail images -->
      <div class="row">
           <div class="column">
                 <img class="demo" src="y" style="width:100%" 
            onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Girl in Room 105">
           </div>
          <div class="column"> 
             <img class="demo cursor" src="" style="width:100%" 
              onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="column">
              <img class="demo cursor" src=""style="width:100%" 
              onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="">
          </div>

    </div>
```

I expected a light grey grooved border-bottom but there tuned out to be no border.

Comment: only `border-bottom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-bottom-style` property defines the style of the border bottom.

The possible values for this property are: *'none|hidden|dotted|dashed|solid|double|groove|ridge|inset|outset|initial|inherit'*.

You should use the `border-bottom` property instead. The `border-bottom` is the shorthand for all the border bottom properties.

[Read more about border-bottom on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom)

Comment: Here's a codepen with your HTML using border-bottom https://codepen.io/littlefinger42/pen/vvxoWj

I can see a border bottom under the content?

Comment: thanks, I found out it was a mistake on my HTML; needed another closing div tag.